# 16.04 Nvidia 304 recurring boot problem

Tags: nvidia

This has been posted before but it is a recurring problem for me.
Every time Ubuntu 16.04 LTS updates the graphics card driver my desktop ether goes into a login loop or won't boot. It has been 5 times already including this morning.  O loose a few hours trying to get this fixed.

Configuration: 16.04.02 on a Lan Party MB with a GeForce 7800GT card.

Current fix is to remove nvidia* drivers and install nvidia-304.131-Oubuntu3.
Once fixed I get around 4 critical errors which I report.

How can this be fixed or how can I tell the OS to not update to the new nvidia  driver.